# Por que variáveis locais são evitadas no Arduino?

Tags: c++, memória, arduino, stack, variáveis-locais

Em diversos exemplo de código para o Arduino noto que quase não há uso de variáveis em escopo local. Um dos exemplos presentes na IDE: `Analog > AnalogInput`:

```cpp
int sensorPin = A0;
int ledPin = 13;
int sensorValue = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(sensorValue);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(sensorValue);
}
```

A variável `sensorValue` é global, enquanto que seu uso está apenas dentro da função `loop`. Outro caso é a biblioteca [*Moving-Average-Filter*](https://github.com/sebnil/Moving-Avarage-Filter--Arduino-Library-). Uma parte do código:

```cpp
#define MAX_DATA_POINTS 20

class MovingAverageFilter {
public:
  MovingAverageFilter(unsigned int newDataPointsCount);
  float process(float in);

private:
  float values[MAX_DATA_POINTS];
  int k;
  int dataPointsCount;
  float out;
  int i;
};
```

Aqui os membros `out` e `i` são usados apenas em `process`, devendo ser locais:

```cpp
float MovingAverageFilter::process(float in) {
  out = 0;

  values[k] = in;
  k = (k+1) % dataPointsCount;

  for (i=0; i<dataPointsCount; i++) {
    out += values[i];
  }

  return out/dataPointsCount;
}
```

Usar variáveis dessa forma parece um absurdo para mim. Isso é proposital? Se sim, qual o motivo?

A única possibilidade que posso imaginar é que o endereço de variáveis locais seria conhecido em tempo de compilação, por isso podem ser acessadas sem levar em conta o registrador da stack. Isso faz realmente diferença?

Mas no caso da classe, não consigo ver como poderia ser mais rápido ler um objeto atravez do ponteiro `this` do que ler ele na stack, relativo ao registrado.

Outra explicação talvez seja evitar ter que alocar um *stack frame* para a função. Mas essa alocação deveria ser tão simples quanto incrementar um registrado, não entendo por que deva ser evitada. Além disso funções que recebem argumentos terão um *stack frame* de qualquer forma.

Comment: Dispor das variáveis desta maneira poderia facilitar a identificação em um eventual dump de memória? (apenas um chute - sou leigo na programação de baixo nível).

Comment: Realmente, é uma questão mais filosófica do que de performance. Pode existir sim uma diferença mínima no acesso ao stack frame ou a memória fixa criada para as globais, mas ambas estão tão perto devido a natureza das aplicações que a diferença não é nem considerável. Prefiro continuar com boas práticas e perder alguns milissegundos de runtime a perder horas de debugging.

Comment: Não entendo de arduino, mas qual é o tamanho disponível para a pilha? É possível que o espaço no arduino para isso seja limitado.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eu pesquisei sobre o assunto e não achei nenhuma boa resposta sobre isso. As razões que consegui levantar são as seguintes:

- Programas escritos para o Arduino são em geral bastante simples e há pouca memória disponível. Como resultado, pouca gente se importa muito com modularização e encapsulamento em programas Arduino.
- Arduino não utiliza um único método `main()` para executar o programa. Ao invés disso, utiliza dois métodos `setup()` e `loop()` independentes. O resultado disso é que para você poder utilizar dentro de `loop()` o que foi definido no `setup()`, você acaba sendo obrigado a utilizar variáveis globais.
- Muitas vezes as variáveis utilizadas no método `loop()` devem ser lembradas entre uma iteração e outra. Isso faz com que você acabe sendo obrigado a utilizar variáveis globais.
- Arduino é simples e limitado demais para que você possa utilizar eventos, callbacks e mensageria de uma forma efetiva.
- A maior parte dos exemplos são escritos para principiantes que sabem pouca coisa sobre C, então tudo é um tanto simplificado demais. Além disso, grande parte dos usuários do Arduino não têm muito interesse, prática ou treinamento na programação de software, pois o foco deles está no hardware.

Discussões úteis, porém inconclusivas, podem ser encontradas [aqui](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,54139.0.html) e [aqui](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=206409.0).

Concluindo: Recomendo seguir as boas práticas de programação tradicionais. Constantes podem ser facilmente otimizadas pelo compilador, então você pode declará-las no escopo global sem problemas (o problema das variáveis globais está quando o valor é alterado, o que não ocorre com constantes). Qualquer coisa que possa mudar de valor, é melhor que fique em um escopo local, a menos que você não tenha escolha. Se for usar o escopo global, lembre-se do modificador `static` para tornar a variável privada e disponibilize funções `getters` e `setters` se precisar exportá-la.

Comment: É isso mesmo. Os primeiros três itens da lista da sua resposta definem tudo. O Arduino é um padrão para placas de microcontroladores de bem baixo nível, para controlar sensores, LEDs etc. Normalmente os controladores suportados tem 32KB ou 256KB de memória para programas e de 20 a 40 portas de entrada e saída. É possível usar classes em C++, mas normalmente não há muitos níveis de abstração, pois não há memória suficiente nem necessidade de abstrair complexidade. Quando a biblioteca utilizada tem classes, normalmente são criadas instâncias em escopo global também.

Comment: Quanto ao uso de memória, o único ganho seria no fato de não se usar a pilha (stack) para armazenamento das variáveis. Nada critico nos exemplos citados, mas em uma função recursiva, por exemplo, faria muita diferença. Entretanto, outra solução seria o uso de variáveis estáticas (static) dentro das funções.

Comment: @AdrianoP uma função recursiva seria justamente um problema já que a alteração de variáveis em uma iteração afetariam as demais. A não ser que a função se chame apenas no final, mas nesse caso *tail call optimization* se aplica e não há alocação de mais stack. Concordo com usar as variáveis como *static*. Ao menos ficaria menos sujo.

Answer (score 6):

Veja o que diz o site do Arduino:

> "Quando os programas começam a ficar grandes e mais complexos,
>   variáveis locais são um jeito útil de assegurar que somente a função
>   tenha acesso a suas próprias variáveis. Isso evita erros de programação quando uma função inadvertidamente modifica variáveis usadas por outra função.
>   Às vezes, é conveniente declarar e inicializar variáveis dentro de um `for`(...)."
>   (http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/scope)

Não é aconselhado o uso indiscrimiado de variáveis globais; devem ser usadas somente quando é necessário acessar seus valores a partir de diferentes blocos. Use constantes ou variáveis locais sempre que possível.

Answer (score 2):

O que acontece é que as variáveis definidas dentro de um escopo são alocadas no frame da função (no stack).

As variávels definidas no global vão direto para o segmento de dados.

A diferença é que enquanto acessar um dado do segmento de dados se usa endereçamento direto, para acessar dados alocados no frame são acessados por endereçamento indireto indexado.

Pra quem entende de ASM Z80, é algo como (AVR usa RISC, não é exatamente isso o que acontece no AVR):

Endereçamento direto:

```
LD A, (VAR_ADDRESS)
```

Endereçamento indireto indexado:

```
LD HL, stack_pointer
LD A, (HL),VAR_INDEX
```

Obvio que a primeira forma é mais rápida, ou seja, consome menos ciclos de processador. Mesmo que exista uma intrução AVR que faça tudo de uma vez só, ainda assim se bate na memória duas vezes: uma para pegar a base, outra para pegar o dado (cujo endereço é calculado a partir da base, o que em si também gasta ciclos de processador).

Então, se você está programando um algoritmo time critical, cada ciclo de processador conta e você vai querer gerar a instrução mais rápida possível. Na maioria das vezes, este ganho é marginal mas vez ou outra faz diferença.

Uma alternativa à variáveis globais é usar variáveis de escopo "static". Elas são alocadas no segmento de dados igualmente, mas apenas o escopo onde ela foi definida é capaz de endereçá-la:

```
float MovingAverageFilter::process(float in) {
  static float out = 0;

  values[k] = in;
  k = (k+1) % dataPointsCount;

  static int i;
  for (i=0; i<dataPointsCount; i++) {
    out += values[i];
  }

  return out/dataPointsCount;
}
```

Um efeito colateral é que ao invés de ter apenas um "i" no universo, cada função que declarar a sua static int i para seus contadores vão alocar um endereço no segmento de dados - 10 funções, 10 variáveis alocando espaço.

Daí que se o seu espaço em RAM tá ficando curto, é melhor então declarar globalmente mesmo para economizar espaço no segmento de dados.

Às vezes, precisamos abrir mão de boas práticas quando lidamos com hardware limitado. Quando se tem apenas 2K de RAM, gastar 40 bytes com 10 contadores de 32 bits podendo fazer o mesmo serviço com apenas 4 bytes pode ser a diferença entre usar um AVR mais barato, ou ter que usar um mais caro.

Se você quer produzir milhares de unidades do seu produto, um chip 1 USD mais caro vai ter custar milhares de USD à mais para fazer o mesmo serviço.

EDIT: notem que eu ignorei solenemente as otimizações do compilador. Um compilador poderia, caso o contador fosse declarado dentro do escopo da função (e usar for(int i = 0....) é uma forma de ajudar o compilador a sacar isso), ele poderia ir direto para um registrador do AVR (ele tem 32!), e com isso se economiza memória e ciclos de processador - nada é mais rápido que usar o registrador!